# Inserting matrix equation

Tags: equations, matrices

I have a difficulty inserting a matrix equation in my document. Here is photo of the matrix:
[image]

Any idea of how to insert this. Do I have to use tiKz for this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can do that with `TikZ` or `pst-node`. If you can  accept dotted lines, you even do not need any of these.

Comment: what's the distinction between the upright and italic "X"?  or should they really be all the same?

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun: something which reproduces your screenshot rather closely.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\tikznode}[2]{\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base)]{\node(#1)[inner sep=0pt]{#2};}}
\begin{document}
\[
 X^{(p)}=\begin{bmatrix}
    \tikznode{11}{\strut} & & 0\\
    & & \\
    \boldsymbol{L}_x^{(p)} & & \tikznode{33}{\strut}\\[0.2cm]
    \tikznode{41}{\strut}~~ & & \tikznode{43}{\strut}\\
    & \boldsymbol{X}^{(p)}_c &\\[0.2cm]
    \tikznode{61}{\strut}~~ & & \tikznode{63}{\strut}\\
    & & \boldsymbol{U}_x^{(p)}\\
    0 & & \tikznode{83}{\strut}
 \end{bmatrix}
\]
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\draw[dashed](11.north)--(33.south east);
\draw[-](41.north west)--(43.north east);
\draw[-](61.north west)--(63.north east);
\draw[dashed](61.west)--(83.south east);}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As Bernard mentioned, there are several different ways of producing similar things.

To make Mico a bit happier, here is a more artistic version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand{\tikznode}[2]{\tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base)]{\node(#1)[inner sep=0pt]{#2};}}
\begin{document}
\[
 X^{(p)}=\begin{bmatrix}
    \tikznode{11}{\strut} & & \tikznode{13}{\strut}\\
    & \tikznode{22}{\strut} & \\
    ~~\boldsymbol{L}_x^{(p)} & & \tikznode{33}{\strut}\\[0.2cm]
    \tikznode{41}{\strut}~~ & & \tikznode{43}{\strut}\\
    & \boldsymbol{X}^{(p)}_c &\\[0.2cm]
    \tikznode{61}{\strut}~~ & & \tikznode{63}{\strut}\\
    & \tikznode{72}{\strut} & \boldsymbol{U}_x^{(p)}~~\\
    \tikznode{81}{\strut} & & \tikznode{83}{\strut}
 \end{bmatrix}
\]
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\draw[dashed](11.north)--(33.south east);
\draw[-](41.north west)--(43.north east);
\draw[-](61.north west)--(63.north east);
\draw[dashed](61.west)--(83.south east);
\node at ($(13)!0.2!(22)$) {\Large0};
\node at ($(81)!0.2!(72)$) {\Large0};
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. The `\boldsymbol{L}_x^{(p)}`, though, seems to be placed a bit too far to the left, and `\boldsymbol{U}_x^{(p)}` seems to be placed a bit too far to the right. Is is straightforward to adjust their horizontal alignments?